# How to get the rgb colors from an already allocated color in PHP GD

Tags: php, colors, gd, rgb

How would you get the colors from an allocated color
something like...

```
$col = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 50, 5);
//A fake function - rgbfromallocate (that I wish I knew)

$rgb = rgbfromallocate($col);
print $rgb['r'];//255
print $rgb['g'];//50
print $rgb['b'];//5
```

Comment: What happens if you just print_r $col? Although untested, the first comment on the [imagecolourallocate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php) page suggests that the function actually simply returns a hexadecimal value made of 4 pairs - alpha, red, green, blue - perhaps it is stored quite simply?

Comment: Stephen: $col is a number representing a color in the image palette. If this image has an RGB palette, like many images do, then what you said would be the case. But however, if the image uses some other palette, then `imagecolorsforindex()` has to be used to get the RGB value of the color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe [`imagecolorsforindex()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorsforindex.php) is what you're looking for?

For example:

```
// $img is an image
$color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 50, 5);

$rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, $color);
print $rgb['red']; // 255
print $rgb['green']; // 50
print $rgb['blue']; // 5
print $rgb['alpha']; // 0, but if the image uses the alpha channel,
// this would have a value of up to 127, which is fully transparent
```

Comment: Works perfect, I had thought that function only worked in use with imagecolorat but that was exactly it.